# ngPattern is not working after upgrading Angular JS 1.2.x to 1.4.x

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern, angularjs-ng-pattern

The pattern validation using angular ngPattern is not working after upgrading the Angular JS library to 1.4.1. See the code below.

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="someForm" role="form" novalidate>
        <div>field1Value = '{{field1Value}}'</div>
        <p class="input-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': someForm.field1.$invalid }">
          <input id="date" name="field1" type="text" 
            ng-model="field1Value" class="form-control" ng-pattern="{{expr1}}" ng-trim="false"  ng-maxlength="10" ng-required="false" ng-disabled="false" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

See the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TfUgC6monFX3j9Luxwrx?p=preview)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I make it worked with the help of custom directive. I am still doubt full why the ngPattern have no inbuilt support. I don't know I make any mistake in my side.

Here is the custom directive.

```
app.directive('fieldPattern',function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs,ngModelCtrl) {
      var dRegex = new RegExp(attrs.fieldPattern);
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
          var isValid = dRegex.test(value);
          ngModelCtrl.$setValidity(attrs.name,isValid);
          if (!isValid) {
            return undefined;
          }
        }
        return value;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

See the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8JetWpWobIIVeHIAEcCi?p=preview)